# Python Permutation String From List

Tags: python-3.x

I have following list that contains string

```py
data=[]
data.append('BBBB')
data.append('AAAA')
data.append('CCCC')
```

How can i make my code print the following result? Each line cannot have repeated values like `BBBBBBBB`.

```
BBBB
AAAA
CCCC
BBBBAAAA
BBBBCCCC
AAAABBBB
... snippet ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might help you out,

```
from itertools import permutations as per

input_nos = int(input('the number of strings'))   #for specifying the input iterations

strings = []

for i in range(input_nos):
    strings.append(input())

strings_per = per(strings, input_nos -1 )  # as specified

for i in strings_per:
    print(''.join(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line solution:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, permutations
>>> print(*chain(*(map("".join, permutations(data, i)) for i in range(1, 3))), sep="\n")
BBBB
AAAA
CCCC
BBBBAAAA
BBBBCCCC
AAAABBBB
AAAACCCC
CCCCBBBB
CCCCAAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strings_list = ['AAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCC', 'DDDD', 'EEEE']

def permute_string(a):
    b = []
    b.extend(a)
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
            b.append(a[i] + a[j])
    return b

permute_string(strings_list)
```

Based on what information you have give, this should do your work.